# Windows Service without Visual Studio interference

Tags: .net, windows-services, designer

I'd like to create and manage a Windows Service application without "help" from Visual Studio's designer.

Since this is .NET, and judging by MSDN and what the designer does, this means inheriting from `Installer`, and constructing and dealing with `ServiceProcessInstaller` and `ServiceInstaller` to be able to manage the install-time execution of the serivce.

Runtime, this means creating a `ServiceBase` subclass and starting it from `Main` using `ServiceBase.Run` (and overriding various `ServiceBase` event handling methods).

However, when I do this, Visual studio insists on treating the `Installer` and `ServiceBase` subclasses as designer-edited files.  This doesn't exactly help readability, not to mention the fact that it generally can't deal with handwritten code at all.  **I'd like to avoid the designer** to keep things manageable (to avoid nebulous who-knows-what-runs-when, particularly for code that's tricky to test and debug such as windows services that after all *must* be installed to be run at all), and also to be able to specify the service name at run-time, rather than at compile time - the designer doesn't support that.

How can I create a windows service application without all the gunk?

Comment: You might want to have a look at the TopShelf project - http://topshelf-project.com/

Comment: hmm - neat!  Looks a little overkill and not quite mature yet, but if I would be writing a new app, I'd definitely consider it.

Answer (score 12):

`ServiceBase` is derived from `Component`. To disable the designer view you can attach the attribute like so:

```
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("Code")]
public class MyService : ServiceBase
{

}
```

Comment: this works, designer is not created provided that you add this line before you add the inheritance.

Comment: This is indeed the correct answer, works like a champ!

Comment: Worked, but I had to remove and re-add reference to `System.ServiceProcess` before this would take effect.

Answer (score 6):

Since I often create services do it like this:

I have a common base class that looks like this:

```
internal class ServiceRunner : ServiceBase {
   protected static void Startup(string[] args, ServiceRunner instance, bool interactiveWait) {    
    if (instance == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("instance");

    if (Environment.UserInteractive) {
        instance.OnStart(args);
        if (interactiveWait) {
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to stop service");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        instance.OnStop();
    }
    else
        Run(instance);
}
```

Then I create all my services like this

```
internal class MyService : ServiceRunner
{
    public MyService() {
        ServiceName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyServiceName"];
    }

    private static void Main(string[] args) {
        Startup(args, new MyService(), true);
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args) {
        base.OnStart(args);
        ...
    }

    protected override void OnStop() {
        ...
        base.OnStop();
    }
}
```

Now I can test the service by just running it in the debugger or on the command line.

When installing I use the command line

```
sc create ServiceName binPath= C:\...\MyService.exe
```

(I have not been able to stop the designer from opening on double click)

Answer (score 2):

Well, just delete the InitializeComponent() call in the constructor and the designer generated code is out of your hair.

Comment: That doesn't work: visual studio is "smart": it doesn't care whether you've added a file as a class or as a component - what matters is the inheritance hierarchy.  If you inherit from `Installer` and thus `IComponent`, you'll get the designer - even if you originally created the file via "Add Class".

Comment: I even tried adding a nonsense class before the `Installer` - it still uses the designer.  A (unsatisfactory) workaround is to do right-click: Open-with and select CSharp Editor and set that as default.  It's unsatisfactory because a fresh source control checkout on another machine will lose that user setting and revert to the please-mess-up-my-code designer.

Comment: I repro.  Annoying, isn't it.

Answer (score -1):

VS does add some extra stuff but I wouldn't really worry about it. Here's a tutorial for creating a simple service manually in VS2005, it should work just fine for new versions, too.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/WindowsService.aspx

Comment: The designer crashes when `ServiceName` is not constant - and it alters code I wrote: I really don't want the designer.  Also, the code it produces is easily 5 times larger than the code necessary, and much less understandable.

Comment: Let me put it this way: is there *any* useful feature for the designer beyond serving as an initial template including the required types?